# From Boltzmann transport equation to fouriers law - infinite speed of propagation of information

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, heat-conduction

The macroscopic Fourier's law can be derived from the Boltzmann transport equation using the relaxation time approximation for the collision integral.

This is demonstrated for an ideal gas in [this lecture](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/A1/2014/A1LectureNotes.pdf) on pages 48-59.

Obviously, Fourier's law contradicts special relativity because the parabolic PDE implies infinite speed of propagation for the heat.

I am wondering, which assumption within the derivation leads to this contradiction.

Is it the assumption of the validity of BTE for microscale itself? (single-particle distribution functions)

Is it the relaxation-time approximation used to linearize the BTE?

Is it the method of moments, used to derive the energy balance equation?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the Maxwellian distribution function (6.11)
$$F \sim  \exp\left({-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{2mT}}\right) $$
The relativistic version should be
$$ F \sim \exp\left({-\frac{\sqrt{m^2+\vec{p}^2}}{T}}\right).$$
And is now a distribution over $\vec{p}$. You could also subtract out the rest mass $m$ in the exponent because it cancels out when you normalize $F$.
(I have used units where $c=k_B=1$ but hopefully it's obvious where they go.)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you for pointing this out